# PHP の ssh2_scp_send でファイルが意図した通り送信できない

Tags: php, cakephp, scp

`$remote_path` がディレクトリ名ではなくファイル名として認識されていしまいます。
指定したディレクトリにファイル送信する方法をご存じの方、よろしくお願い致します。

（例）`\home\user\test.csv` といったファイルができてしまう。
　　　ディレクトリ `\home\user` に `test.csv` がファイル送信されない。

```
if (!ssh2_scp_send($connection, $local_path.$fileName, $remote_path.$fileName, 0644)) {
    // error処理
}
```

環境：xampp+PHP7.1

Answer (score 0):

`ssh2_scp_send` の第三引数に指定するのは (ディレクトリではなく) 常に**ファイル**のパスです。

**参考:**
[ssh2_scp_send - PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.ssh2-scp-send.php)

> ```php
> ssh2_scp_send(
>     resource $session,
>     string $local_file,
>     string $remote_file,
>     int $create_mode = 0644
> ): bool
> ```
>
> ##### パラメータ
>
> - remote_file
>   リモートファイルへのパス。

Comment: ssh2_scp_send では、指定したディレクトリにファイル送信できないということでしょうか？
その場合、どのように指定のディレクトリにファイル転送すればよろしいのでしょうか？
ssh2_exec($connection, "cd \home\user");などを事前に記載してみたのですが指定のディレクトリにファイル転送できませんでした。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。
ファイルパスの「/」の文字の連結方法が悪かったようです。